# Does GCP spend-based CUD cover spot N2D cpu/mem?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Does spend-based CUD cover Spot N2D VMs? According to the docs resource-based CUD does not cover Spot machines, but it is not mentioned that spent-based CUD does or doesn't cover Spot machines in the docs.

I almost always use  Spot machine in the GKE cluster, so if it does, that's a lot of help on bills.

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Flex CUDs are spend-based CUDs for GCE that allow customers to commit to an amount of spend that covers all regions and most machine types, unlike resource-based CUDs. Spot instances are nothing short of machines which automatically stop after 24 hrs and it's mainly used for temporary purposes.
Flex CUDs apply to GKE and Dataproc usage (when an applicable machine type is used), because they utilize GCE instances. Since GCE instances are covered they are considered for Spot VM. Flexi CUD's cover spot VM's also because they utilize GCE instances. Check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/committed-use-discounts-overview#spend_based) where it says the Compute Engine instances are covered in the example shown. For details, better contact the [sales team](https://cloud.google.com/contact).